# Generating an absolutely unique string in php

Tags: php, random

Im not looking for a code for generating random AN string,but a better way of doing that.

Right now im using the `uniqid()` function for generating random unique strings,which should for unique for even a millionth time.

Yes I can't make it absolutely unique and its not possible unless I check each time the one im generating with the database and logging when a new one is generated.But imagine if there are a billion strings logged, and in order to check the uniqueness its going to take so much of time moving through each and every row.

IS there any better way I can generate random reference strings,which will be absolutely unique?Is the way in which , checking for uniqueness through the database a better way?

Please suggest some solution

Comment: @DavidJones This is not a duplicate of the one you mentioned and my question is different from the one you mentioned.

Comment: I don't know in what level it should be unique, but I guess `hash("whirlpool",time());` would do a good job.

Comment: The only way to ensure that your string is 100% unique is to store a list of strings you've previously used... so, you're looking at a database solution with a `UNIQUE` index; if there's a UNIQUE index you'll never have to check that it's unique, it'll fail on INSERT and you'll have to try another string if it's a duplicate. The question is though, do you *really* need that level of uniqueness? (creating transaction ids for a payment gateway would be a "yes").

Comment: @cd001 exactly the one i wanted to ask.Im using that one for a payment gateway.So i need a unique reference number for each of the transaction.I can expect a large amount of strings in the db

Comment: If you generate anything based on `time()` or even `microtime()`, keep in mind that you get duplicates when called within the same second/microsecond. This happens very often on a normal webserver!

Comment: As long as you are using a database which supports primary keys then the answer to your question is extremely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to generate unique strings: "0001", "0002", "0003", ... "9999" are all unique.  If you want something that is both unique *and* where you cannot tell what the next one will be, then use some form of encryption.  Since encryption is reversible, then unique inputs will result in unique outputs.  Just encrypt: "0001", "0002", "0003", etc. with a suitable cipher and you will get a series of unique strings where the next member of the set is not obvious, except to someone who has the key.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the current time and hash this, and in addition for extra uniqueness (because this changes only per second) you could add a random number to the end before hashing it; like follows:

```
$string = time() . mt_rand(1,10000);
hash("whirlpool",$string);
```

however there is still a tiny chance of duplicates, this chance is very small.

**edit**
changed `rand()` to `mt_rand()` because `rand()` still is some kind of guessable.

Comment: Do not use `rand()` if the generated id is sensitive information.

Comment: care to explain why @ToBe, this generates a combination of rand() and time(), there is near no way to get duplicates..

Comment: No, my concern here is that results from `rand()` are predictable and can lead to security problems if used in such contexts. You could use `mt_rand()`.

Comment: However the chance is very small that you could guess + apply this on the perfect time due to the rand() function, ill update my awnser. ;)

Comment: There are tools that can predict IDs with only a small sample set, even with small alterations like time(). You would be surprised ;)

Comment: yeah, but because of the server's time you literaly have 1 second to apply that. and after that you would need to regenerate a new ID :p

Comment: Since rand() is predictable and time() certainly is predictable, any permutation of both is predictable too. But anyways, since mt_rand is there, just use it and be done ;)

Answer (score 0):

could you not just use the server time as a unique string and if you have multiple strings at the same time do a quick query as there shouldn't be that many in the database with the exact time and just increment it...

Or you could just use a database with a unique primary row so 1,2,3.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using uniqid(), then you can continue to do so, but you have to implement a check in your database. With PDO, you can achieve it like this:

```
$run = 1;
$done = 0;
while (!$done) {
    if ($run) {
        $unique_id = uniqid();
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE unique_id = :unique_id");
    } else {
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table('unique_id') VALUES (:unique_id)");
        $done = 1;
    }
    $statement->bindValue(":unique_id", $unique_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $run = $statement->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: `uniquid` can return same ids when called in same microsecond.

Comment: So your point is...? I'm checking if that's already in the DB, if not, then inserting it. In MyISAM, you cannot run 2 queries at the same time, so queries are queuing. With other database engines, you can use transactions (insert `$this->db->beginTransaction();` in the beginning and `$this->db->commit();` at the end.

Comment: The point is that you would have to run SQL queries for at least one microsecond until you get a new id that has a chance of being unique in your db. Yes, it would work, but depending on your hardware you would have to execute a couple of DB queries without need.

Answer (score 0):

Uniquid is fairly unique already and is based on the current timestamp so future values wont match past values. It just has a problem when two requests come in in the same millisecond.

This small function generates a secure and unique string. It **does not** check if that value is already present, but chances are extremely low for that and should be enough in almost all cases.

```
function better_uniqid($length = 12){
    $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(ceil($length / 2));
    return bin2hex($data);
}
```

This function relys on the openssl extension and PHP 5.3+

http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

This function also avoids potentially unsafe methods like rand().